# Edit functions in Flask views interactively

Tags: python, flask, ipython

I'd like to play with a function from the views module of a Flask app interactively.

I import the module into IPython, then make some minor changes - e.g. delete a few print statements, and then try to reload the module.

The module won't reload; instead it returns an AssertionError.

```
In[1]: import app.views as av
In[2]: test_result = av.test() # Do something
In[3]: %edit app/views.py  # Make some minor change
In[4]: reload(av)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: user
```

I'm trying to figure out what raises this error.

I think that it's raised because view names need to be unique. From the first import all the url endpoints in the views module were defined in the namespace. When I try to reload it, the AssertionError is raised because now the url endpoints aren't unique.

Flask can't overwrite the old endpoints, even though it'd just be overwriting them with themselves.

Is there anything that I can do to get around this to edit functions in the views module?

Comment: The best way to debug code is using a proper debuger. Try use `pdb` at point you want to debug.

Comment: @Mauro Baraldi - the point is to access functions interactively.

Comment: @ABM Can you post a minimal example? You could try to manually delete the old endpoints.

Comment: @syntonym not sure what a minimal example would contain. This should happen regardless of the contents in the views module.